# Using Mock for fields that are instances of one class

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have a classes:

```
public class Sender {
    private final SomeClass firstField;
    private final SomeClass secondField;
    private Sender(SomeClass firtsField, SomeClass secondField){
        this.firstField = firstField;
        this.secondField = secondField;
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SenderTest{
    @Mock
    private firstField;
    @Mock
    private secondField;
}
```

Everything are looking grade, but looks like it injects the same objects in two fields or something like this. When I am trying to use when(..).thenReturn() for one field it sets data two another and vise verse; And the most strange that it works fine in debug mode. What can you say?

Comment: How are you running the Test? Maybe recompile every class

Comment: The Fields in SenderTest are missing their type. Furthermore how is Sender initialized in your test?

Comment: @Leonard I think it's just not quite good MCVE

Answer (score 1):

Mockito has some problems with constructor injection of two or more fields of the same type. But it works perfectly if you use setter injection.

So you can refactor "Sender" class like this:

```
    public class Sender {
        private SomeClass firstField;
        private SomeClass secondField;
        public void setFirstField(SomeClass firstField) {
            this.firstField = firstField;
        }
        public void setSecondField(SomeClass secondField) {
            this.secondField= secondField;
        }
    }
```

Remember that if class has both the constructor and setters, Mockito will choose the constructor for injection and completely ignore setters.

**Edit**: if you definitely need to use constructor for some reason, you can always mock fields manually instead of using Mockito annotations.
So in your case Sender would stay the same and SenderTest would be like this:

```
public class SenderTest {

    private SomeClass firstField;
    private SomeClass secondField;

    private Sender sender;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        firstField = Mockito.mock(SomeClass.class);
        secondField = Mockito.mock(SomeClass.class);

        sender = new Sender(firstField, secondField);
    }

    @Test
    public void smokeTest() {

    }
}
```

Comment: What I can do in case that fields are `final` ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what `SomeClass` is itself. It it a data  (POJO) object, it's worth to create them in test (and i.e. fill with random generated values).

If it is a service. It can be sign for a architecture problem. why do you need two copies of the same service? Probably it makes sense to do some refactoring.